# draw() method is not being called in GMaps Overlay Method

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My draw() method in a custom overlay class that extends LazyMarker from the Google Maps extension library is not being called and I'm not sure why.  Here is my method:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, GoogleMap mapView, boolean shadow)
{
  Log.e("SegmentOverlay2", "Shadow Value:"+shadow);
  super.draw( canvas, mapView, shadow );
  if( !shadow )
  {
     Log.e("SegementOverlay2", "Projection VALUE SEGMENTOVERLAY2: "+mapView.getProjection());
     mProjectionProxy.setProjection( mapView.getProjection() ); 
     draw(canvas);
  }
}
```

I'm currently using GMaps V2.  What is wrong with my code?  This this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you post any more code, such as your whole `LazyMarker` sub-class and how you're adding the class to your `GoogleMap`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing Android API v1 and v2. If you had an application that used API v1, you cannot just replace `MapView` with `GoogleMap` and think it will work.

The easiest way to migrate is to remove all the code that used API v1 and write it from scratch using these directions: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Android Maps Extensions has API that extends API from Google Maps Android v2 and will not help you in migration either.